# Zurb Foundation Abide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, zurb-foundation

Cannot get my form to submit using the Foundation 5 Abide code. If it take out the validation the code/ajax form submits perfectly. See code below, I'm sure I'm missing something. The form is only checking for valid email addresses right now, though I will add in checking for the first name and last name fields later if I can get this one validation to work first.

Form:

```
<form method="post" name="adduser" id="adduser" data-abide="ajax">
<fieldset>
<legend>Add New User</legend>    

<div class="small-2 columns">
<label class="inline">First Name
<input type="text" name="fname"/>
</label>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns">
<label class="inline">Last Name
<input type="text" name="lname"/>
</label>
</div>

<div class="small-4 columns">
<label class="inline">Email
<input type="email" name="email"/>
</label>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns">
<label class="inline">Access Type
<select  name="accesslvl">
<option value="1" selected>User</option>
<option value="2">Admin</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns">
<input type="submit" class="button small adduserbtn" value="Add User" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('#adduser').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {

     $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'addnewuser.php',
          data: $('form').serialize(),
          success: function () {
               alert('User has been added successfully');
               window.location.reload(true);
          }
      });
});
```

Previous to adding the validation into the equation, I was submitting the form via this script, which was working fine and still does work when I remove the data-abide settings from the form.

```
 $('form').on('submit', function (a) {

      a.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'addnewuser.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('User has been added successfully');
          window.location.reload(true);
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: What validation patterns have you tried? Seems to work fine here: http://codeply.com/go/JrO7FEazMr

Comment: There are no patterns, the only field that is being validated is the email field, which is using the default Zurb Foundation 5 validation. And the validation works. The part that doesn't work is the submitting of the form, the AJAX part. Everything under the $.ajax section does not run. I have added the original script to the original question above that I was using before the validation and it works fine.